# Falling yo-yo: equation of motion, speed and change in momentum

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is: A ﻿yo-yo ﻿consists ﻿of ﻿two ﻿uniform ﻿discs, ﻿each ﻿of ﻿mass ﻿M ﻿and ﻿radius ﻿R,
﻿connected ﻿by ﻿a ﻿short ﻿light ﻿axle ﻿of ﻿radius ﻿a ﻿around ﻿which ﻿a ﻿portion ﻿of ﻿a ﻿thin ﻿string ﻿is ﻿wound. ﻿One ﻿end ﻿of ﻿the ﻿string ﻿is ﻿attached ﻿to ﻿the ﻿axle ﻿and ﻿the ﻿other ﻿to ﻿a ﻿fixed ﻿point ﻿P. ﻿The ﻿yo-yo ﻿is ﻿held ﻿with ﻿its ﻿centre ﻿of ﻿mass ﻿vertically ﻿below ﻿P ﻿and ﻿then ﻿released.

How can I find the following:

a. ﻿Assuming ﻿that ﻿the ﻿unwound ﻿part ﻿of ﻿the ﻿string ﻿remains ﻿approximately ﻿vertical, ﻿how can I use ﻿the ﻿principle ﻿of ﻿conservation ﻿of ﻿energy ﻿to ﻿find ﻿the ﻿equation ﻿of ﻿motion ﻿of ﻿the ﻿centre ﻿of ﻿mass ﻿of ﻿the ﻿yo-Yo?

b. If ﻿the ﻿string ﻿has ﻿length ﻿L, ﻿what ﻿is ﻿the ﻿speed ﻿of ﻿the ﻿yoyo ﻿just ﻿before ﻿it ﻿reaches ﻿the ﻿end? ﻿Explain ﻿what ﻿happens ﻿next. ﻿What ﻿is ﻿the ﻿change ﻿in ﻿momentum ﻿
(I.e.﻿the ﻿so ﻿called ﻿impulse)﻿due ﻿to ﻿the ﻿tension ﻿in ﻿the ﻿string ﻿at ﻿this ﻿time?

Comment: That is the problem but do you have a question about it? Nobody knows what you know. You need to say what you have tried, where you got stuck, then people can help you from there.

Comment: Also, as a general rule, in this forum, you should convert it from a physics problem into a math problem before you ask the question. If you do not know how to convert it to mathematics, you should ask it in the physics forum. But in either place, you need to try your best to solve it yourself first, and explain in your question what you've tried and where you are having problems. (And please don't say "I don't know where to start". The answer to that is to read and try it.)